# TV IR remote codes discovery for Android

Tags: remote-control

I have an Android phone with an IR blaster and I can use it to control my Sony TV.

However I have an other device - TCL L24B2500 TV. I don't have a remote for it and want to use my phone instead. But I cannot, as TCL brand is not supported by the application and I couldn't find the codes in public databases.

So I need to guess the correct control codes to put into Android IR Remote apps. Are there any application to guess, or I am out of luck (no apps or search space is too large)?

I know that there are devices to capture the codes from remotes, but I don't have a working remote to start from.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this app (Smart IR Remote - AnyMote).](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remotefairy)
When I tried using other apps I often found that they couldn't support old devices in my house, but this app has a plethora of devices and it supports many old products.